# Projection matrix and orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection-matrices

let $L$ be the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space determined by the vector (1,1,1)T. Let $P$ be the projection matrix for the projection onto the line $L$. Determine the matrix $P$ and then:

a) Determine the orthonormal basis of the orthonormal complement $L \perp $ of the line $L$.

b) Determine the projection of the vector (1,2,3)T on the line $L$.

c) Determine the projection of the vector (1,2,3)T onto the orthogonal complement $L \perp$ of the line L.

Could you help me to understand and solve this task? How to find matrix $P$, orthogonal complement, projection of vector on plane...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Use [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on e.g. the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$ You will get as first column vector a normalized vector pointing in direction of $L$, but the other two vectors will be an orthonormal basid of $L^\bot$

For (b) use [wikipedia formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) with respect to the orthonormal basis found in 1.

For (c) dito (b) but with the complement basis.

Comment: what is that matrix that you entered? How did you got it?

Comment: I started with a column vector defining $L$ and appended arbitrary vectors to form a basis. I took vectors from the standard basis. E.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ would also work, but probably gave you a different basis for $L^\bot$.

Comment: thank you very much, do you know how to find matrix P and the b) and c) part? I'm preparing for my final exam, I need urgent answer...

Comment: what about matrix P? how to find it?